# Laravel 8.X - How to generate auth files/scaffolding in the absence of make:auth command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to port a legacy/joomla code into larvel framework. I am trying to reuse old database tables with laravel 8.16. I have added the following columns  in the existing users table

> created_at,
> updated_at,
> remember_token

Now, when i try to run 'php artisan make:auth'. The command is not available. What should I do or which command should I use to create scaffolding?

Comment: add `laravel/ui` package using `composer require laravel/ui`

Comment: I did that. Shall i use ui:auth instead of make:auth? I mean i cannot still see make:auth after installing laravel/ui package @MikeRoss

Comment: There's also laravel/breeze. https://github.com/laravel/breeze. With a single install command it generates controllers, views, requests and routes. Uses tailwind css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Laravel UI installation

At first, install `laravel ui` by running below command

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

### Add UI scaffolding

You can add ui view by running:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

And add authentication controllers by running

```
php artisan ui:controllers
```